# Oracle original Import tool IMP: Flag SHOW=Y does not print DML?

Tags: oracle, import, dml

recently I did some tests with the Oracle original Import tool "IMP" for preparing a migration from Oracle Database 8 to Oracle Database 12.

In that process I did some "dry-runs" using the `SHOW=Y`, `FULL=Y` and `ROWS=Y` parameters of IMP.

Am I missing something or is `SHOW=Y` in general not printing any DML statements? In a scenario like `... ROWS=Y SHOW=Y FULL=Y LOG=mylog.log ...` I would have expected that the output would contain `INSERT` statements. Instead, `mylog.log` shows `. . skipping table "FOOBAR"` where I hoped to find `INSERT INTO FOOBAR ...`.

If I - on the other hand - run the actual import (i.e. omitting `SHOW=Y` in the "IMP" parameter line), DML obivously seems to be executed: Data is written into the tables.

[Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm#i1021478) seems to be not that precise on this topic.

Can someone please shed light into the dark? :-)

Answer (score 0):

`show=y` is meant to only show how import would be processed without actually restoring anything...
from your [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm#i1021478)
:

> You can also display the contents of an export file without actually
>   performing an import. To do this, use the Import SHOW parameter. See
>   SHOW for more information.

look - show contents of dump file, not show statements

**Update**:
exp dump file does not have any insert statement - it is binary

Comment: Maybe my post was a bit confusing:

The output of a `SHOW=Y` (either to stdout or via `LOG=...`) contains - more or less - readable plaintext SQL of what's inside a 'EXP' dump file. What puzzles me is the fact that if I combine `SHOW=Y` with `ROWS=Y`, the ouput contains DDL and DCL code, but no DML code which I would expect because of the `ROWS=Y` flag (documentation says: `ROWS: Specifies whether or not to import the rows of table data.`).

But if omit the `SHOW=Y` flag (leaving `ROWS=Y`) with the purpose of actually writing the dump file to the database, DDL, DCL *and* DML is being written.

Comment: @kwirschau I get it. you want sometheing like --inserts flag to pg_dump?.. Oracle dmp does not have it as far as I remember.

Comment: Hm, yes, I guess that might go in the right direction ... maybe I shoud rather migrate to PostgreSQL instead to a recent Oracle release ... ;-)

Comment: they both have strong advantages and lacks against each other :)